# How to store html content to variable using php

Tags: php, html

I have to send a mail with HTML format using PHP. For that I need to store a HTML content to a variable.

```
$message ="Details: Mail Details";
```

I have to pass the HTML content to the $message variable.
Is it possible?Please help.

Comment: Your code sample doesn't show you trying to use HTML in the string.

Comment: `$message = '<h1>This would be an HTML headline</h1>';` ...?

Comment: If you don't want to escape doublequotes and you have a static/hardcoded HTML string in your php-code, then you could use a Heredoc String: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: actualy in the $message variable already I have some information(String). I want append the HTML content with that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php
$message = "
<html>
<body>
Name: $name<br/>
Phone: $phone
</body>
</html>
";
?>
```

Comment: Like Visit the certificate details page to know more about the package<html><body>Filename test.zip</body</html> (in mail)

Comment: @SoundaryaE are you sending a plain text email or a HTML-formatted email? If it's printing the code in the email, then likely you're sending it in plain-text format (or, the email client you're using to test with cannot display HTML emails)

Comment: @SoundaryaE You will have to set header in the email as $headers = "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

Comment: I will try the above suggesstions